# Keep javascript of an iFrame loaded in background

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have embedded a 3d viewer inside an iFrame and everything works so far, but the viewer has to load many assets, so that the loading time is between 2-3 minutes. This would be fine if the user didn't have to reload the whole viewer and its assets every time they reload the page.

I can't really edit the source code of the 3d viewer, because I didn't write it and it is very complex.

**Is there a way to store the current state of the iFrame's javascript and simply render it again when the site is reloaded?**

Comment: Unless the site already requests such a feature, there is not.